# What exactly was God trying to achieve?

Tags: preacher, preacher-2016

In the *Preacher* series we know for sure that:

1. God is gone from Heaven
2. He wants to start the Apocalypse using the Grail organisation
3. He has a potential replacement race

But then towards the end of the series, God's plan gets a bit more confusing:

> first he sends Jesse to Hell, then it seems that he is trying to show Jesse that "It's hard to be a God" because all good deeds can be turned to bad (attempt to bring peace between two Bedouins kills them both, attempt to save the kid from the brothel kills the child, the sad fate of Pilot Steve etc). After that, he tries to force Jesse to give up on Genesis finally asking just to be loved.

So what was God actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Does he, perhaps, move in mysterious ways?

Comment: Just by reading the title alone and looking at the mess all around the world, this question is way less sci-fi than intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately God wants to be loved and worshiped. Humanity was not doing that as much as he wanted and so he decided to wipe them out and start again.

However humanity has free will and so the apocalypse must be humanity's choice, they must make a decision to welcome the savior and accept the end of the world.

All of Gods plans revolve around this and Custer was a key part, the miniature figures show God has been controlling Jesse Custer since before season 4, he has ensured that his every action brought him here. He ultimately decided to make Jesse the one person that he based the entire future of the human race on, this may be because genesis chose him, or maybe Genesis chose Custer because he was so central to Gods plan. That has not been explained.

However God needs to break Custer, to ensure that he will not interrupt his plans but also because, ultimately, god is a bit of a dick who needs to be worshiped and loved.

So he sends Custer on his pilgrimage to Australia and shows him that every action has a reaction and that no good deed goes unpunished, he also, ultimately tries to prove to Custer that whatever he tries God will win, in killing Custer God knows Tulip and Cassidy will get his son allowing the grail to re capture him.

Eventually he wants to prove to Custer that he can't win, hence a test that Custer can't pass (the throne) and bringing him back from hell to understand that through his actions Humanity has been judged, by taking away Jesses control and keeping him on edge he makes sure that Jesse is not in a position to try and use Genesis against him.

Comment: Very good answer! One point: Genesis has chosen Jesse because he is a perfect balance of good and evil  - Grail managed to replicate this genetically and were planning to put it into Humperdoo somewhere in season 2 I believe.

Comment: Killing Custer isn't what led to the Grail capturing Humperdoo. God knew where he was all along. He was just waiting for Starr to ask.

Comment: We assume God always knew where he was, but I think it more likely God didn't have a clue but knew that after that set of events he would end up with Tulip and Cassidy. Its the old telling someone, you should have just asked me, 5 mins after reading the answer yourself.

Comment: @Yasskier, if you are happy to give the answer a point can I ask what is missing that would make you happy to mark it as answering the question (clicking on the tick)